# Excel Macro VBA Scrolling up not working

Tags: vba, excel, setfocus

my current sheet has rows 1-11 as a frozen pane, and 12 to 12.end(xldown) as an autofilter. whenever a filter is applied and my focus is on a much higher row (say row 100), my list looks short due to the fact my screen isn't scrolling all the way up to reveal the full autofilter. I know the easy solution is just to push up on my mouses scroll wheel, but this file isn't just for me.

Looking for a code that will snap the focus to the top(first) row of my autofilter.

Ive tried:

```
range("c12").select;
range("c12").activate;
range("c11").cells(1,0).select;
range("c11").cells(1,0).activate;
activewindow.scrollrow = 1;
activewindow.scrollrow = 12;
```

and none work. not sure what to try anymore. any ideas?

[Image of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knkCY.png)

Comment: `Range("C12").Select` should do it, you're not using a semi colon (;) in your code are you?

Comment: im not actualy adding a semi colon, im just showing you guys the next line i tried so not to be confused with multi line code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1  ' or any number to get what you want
```

I agree with @Corrosive 2, you souldn't have semi-colons

Comment: im not actualy adding a semi colon, im just showing you guys the next line i tried so not to be confused with multi line code. :P

Comment: @benmazor Ok, wasn't sure. Thank you for voting !

Comment: Found the issue, i was saying ActiveSheet. Not ActiveWindow. thanks your code gave me the hint